# DialogFragment behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, dialog

Hi I have used this DialogFragment to display date picker in my app

```
public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        public DateDialogFragment()
        {
        }
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            showSetDate(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
        }

        }

    public void showSetDate(int year,int month,int day) {
    text.setText(year+"/+"+month+"/"+day);
    }
```

If have used the same in my previous apps. 
Recently it DateDialogFragment behaving strangly. In Eclipse it is showing the error DateDialogFragment should be static.But When I clean the project once. It doesn't showing any error in the project and it runs perfectly. I have gone through this [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and it confirms that it needs class to be static. But why is it allowing me use this eventhough I haven't give static when I clean the project. This happens recently previously it hasn't show any error like this. The same is not showing any error when I share the project with my team members. Why is it behaving like this..

Comment: Is your `DialogFragment` an inner (nested) class?

Comment: @Eric yes it is the inner class in the class that Extends FragmentActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is because Android sometimes needs to instantiate that `Fragment` on its own. This applies to *any* `Fragment`.

When you create a `static` inner class, that means it is not tied to any specific instance of the outer class. So let's say you have:

```
public class A {
  public static class B {
    // ...
  }
  public class C {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In this case, you cannot do `new C()` from outside `A` because all instances of `C` belong to an `A` object. You *can*, however, do `new B()` or `new A.B()`.

The same applies to the fragment; Android cannot do `new DateDialogFragment()` if the class is not static. The reason you are not getting an error (though Lint *should* be telling you) is because you are instantiating the `DateDialogFragment` yourself.

However, if you trigger something like an orientation change and don't recreate the `Fragment` manually, Android will do it for you. Being unable to do so, it will crash.

If the class *is* static, however, Android *can* create an instance of it. Therefore, a nested `Fragment` class should *always* be `static`.

Comment: @Eric great explanation and great Example...I have used this in my previous apps. I don't have a orientation issue because I have set fixed orientation in the application level. Previous apps are already published. Will it cause any problem to my previous apps? something like application crash ?

Comment: If there is an orientation change that is not handled by you, then it will likely crash. If I were you I'd grab a device and test out your old apps to find out for sure. (It's possible you've handled the creation in such a way that Android never touches it.)

Comment: Surely I will do the same...sorry to bother you..but Why the errors are not displaying when I clean the project?

Comment: I honestly don't know why they're disappearing, they definitely should not. It's possible that if you [run the Lint check](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html#eclipse) again, they'll reappear.